# Wait until onDataChange() completes before continuing the method

Tags: java, android, firebase, methods, synchronize

I have a block of code that gets called before another block of code. I want the first block of code to execute entirely before the other code gets called as it is null otherwise. The code is shown below

```
public void displayGraph1() {
        xnumsList = new ArrayList<>();
        namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        xxx = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("child");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    key = child.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference checkingWhoisInWhatChild = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("child").child(key);
                    checkingWhoisInWhatClass.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            String module = dataSnapshot.child("a").getValue().toString();
                            String xnum = dataSnapshot.child("b").getValue().toString();
                            for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfModules.size(); i++) {

                                String lecturerModule = arrayOfModules.get(i);
                                if (module.equals(lecturerModule)) {
                                    xxx.add(xnum);
                                }
                            }                          
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
                }                
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //null array
        for (int i = 0; i < xxx.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("dddd", "arraycontents" + xxx.get(i));
        }
```

Obviously this is not the whole method but my point is that the loop at the bottom gets called before the preceding code due to asynchronous calls. I want a way to make sure that the code above is executed first so that the size of the array in the loop is not null. I have debugged the code and the array is not empty / null normally so I'm 100% sure that this is an asynchronous call that is causing the issue of the empty array in the loop. I'm looking for a way to synchronize the code, I have tried using the keyword "synchronized" on the functions and I have even tried to make a single thread for the entire function but this hasn't proven to work for me. Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: It is, in fact, the result of `addValueEventListener` being an asynchronous call.  You sholdn't try to do anything to change that fact - *never block the main thread* - just make sure that your loop only executes after the callback is invoked by putting the code inside the callback, or using one of the usual methods of async programming.

Comment: I have tried this but i still get the same issue. It is because I have nested for loops which are needed for this code block

Comment: Your for loops make things a little tricky. You could try checking a counter variable within your callback to keep track of when all of the callbacks have been processed. Then, you can execute the rest of your code once they've all returned.

Comment: Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** out.